# Is it possible to make "Minimize" action send window to bottom of Alt+Tab stack in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, window-manager, alt-tab

I want a window to go to the "back of the stack" of the Alt+Tab list when I minimize it.

Currently, if I minimize a window and then press Alt+Tab, I return to the same window.

I'm using Windows 11 Home 10.0.22621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The programming for the Windows 11 Desktop and Task Bar interfaces is new with Windows 11 and is not much customizable.

What you would like to do is not natively available now or in the immediate future (I also run Windows 11 Insider).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is very sad to hear, as it breaks my workflow.

Comment: Being able to minimize to the back of the queue was great. Not sure why Microsoft can't provide such a simple option!